# Transforming JSON before binding to an object in a .net core controller

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I'm trying to bind the JSON, that's coming from a source I cannot control, to a custom class in a controller. The problem that I ran to is the fact that the array of values are sent in format [{'value': 'value1'}, [{'value':'value2'}]. I know that I can create an object that would have one field 'value' and the binding would work, but I want to avoid that and get all the values from the request bound to a string list.

I have this controller method

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> UploadData(List<DataModel> values)
```

And here's how I'd like the DataModel to look like.

```
public class DataModel
{
        public string? a{ get; set; }
        public List<string>? b{ get; set; }
}
```

And here's how the example of data

```
[{
    "a": "name",
    "b": [
        {
        "value": "one"
        }, 
        {
        "value": "two"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Is there a way to achieve this, preferably using an attriubte?

Comment: That's not a good idea and definitely not supported without a lot of custom code. `values` is supposed to be the API DTO model. It should match the actual payload. It's the action's responsibility to apply any transformations if needed and map it to business entities or data objects. If `b` has a stable schema, you can easily create another DTO type, eg `record B(string value);` and use `List<B>`. That's essentially the "attribute" you're looking for.  If the schema isn't stable, you can use `List<Dictionary<string,string>>`

Comment: Okay, I've really wanted to avoid the 'record B(string value);' part, since accessing the values will feel weird (b.B.Value), thanks.

Comment: *Why*? Why do you want to use a different API DTO from the actual API DTO? That's what you're talking about here. ` the values will feel weird` you can map the API DTO to an application entity/class/object, eg using `AutoMapper` or a `new Whatever {...}` clause. AutoMapper was built to flatten complex API DTOs into flatter application entities based on naming conventions, eg flattening `Product.Name` into `ProductName`

Comment: Because it makes the usage of the DataModel so much more clunky. And I don't want to use another model and map to it, since this would break the convention used in my project.

Comment: You're already breaking that convention by using a different API DTO and looking to map it to your internal type. The attributes you're looking for *are* mapping code. Hidden/magic mapping code is a lot clunkier.

Comment: It wouldn't be hidden if there would be an attribute right above the method/class.

Comment: You're asking for a custom attribute with application-defined behavior. The closest to this is a [custom converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0)  applied to `b` through the `JsonConverter` attribute. You can't register such a converter globally because `List<T>` and `string` are general-purpose types, used in multiple properties

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried, but It seems that I couldn't have List<DataModel> in the parameter of the controller method. I kept getting a json parse exception when trying to apply it.

Comment: You can. What *did* you try? Given how big the difference is, you may have to create a converter that takes a JSON snippet and produces an entire `List<string>` or apply the converter to the entire `DataModel` class

Answer (score 0):

Leave the binding object exactly as it should be to map from the source you can't control and just make a custom getter for the object that transforms it in a list like you want. Using automapper or other suggested third party libs will add an unnecessary layer of complexity.

```
public class DataModel
{
    public string? a { get; set; }
    public List<ObjectFromSource> b{  get; set; }
    [NonSerialized]
    public string getb()
    {
        //returns a string list
        return string.Join(",", b.Select(x => x.value));
    }
}
public class ObjectFromSource
{
    public string? value { get; set; }
}
```

then when you need the value around you just call

```
DataModel x = new DataModel();
x.getb();
```

Answer (score 0):

the simpliest way is to change the action input parameter type

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadData(JArray jArr) 
{
  List<DataModel> values = jArr.Select(ja => new DataModel { a = (string)ja["a"], 
                  b = ja["b"].Select(b => (string)b["value"]).ToList() }).ToList();

//your code

}
```

another way is to use a JsonConstructor

```
public class DataModel
{
    public string? a { get; set; }
    public List<string>? b { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConstructor]
    public DataModel (JArray b)
    {
        this.b= b.Select(b => (string)b["value"]).ToList();
    }
    public DataModel() {}
}
```